# EF second transaction get Underlying provider failed on open

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

This is prior to EF 6. My company has a process that works with all of our other clients expect one. The process opens a connection to the clients database, reads out 1000 records at a time, and commits it to our database.

For this client, we read and commit the first 1000 records just fine. When it starts to read again I get "Underlying provider failed on Open". I understand that EF transactions open and close for each read, so when it tries to reopen the connection to do the next read is when it is failing.

Details: We connect through a VPN to the client database.

The code flow is:

```
  connection.open()

  create datareader

  while datareader.read()
  get 1000 records
  bulk commit
  db.SaveChanges
  get next 1000 records
  and so on until it gets all records
```

After the first SaveChanges is when we get the error. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's how you coded your "get next 1000 record" That's kinda hard to do correctly in Entity. Is this function working in other situation ? It fail just for this client ? If it's just this client, just find what is different for him.

Comment: Yeah it's just this client.

Comment: Does he have exactly 1000 records ? Just wondering

Comment: No, the troublesome one has around 7k records and the one that works has around 160k records.

Comment: Wait, you load the data from one database and save to the other? When is the error thrown then? On the second save or the second time you load the next 1000 records? Can you post the actual code? It's not quite clear what you do from the pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. Turns out that the connection being lost was to our database and not the client's. Not entirely sure why, but what seemed to help was putting our BulkInsert method to create the SqlBulkCopy object inside of a using block. We also, at the point at which it failed, reestablished the connection. It's a little hacky, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to EF6 the DbContext was closing the connection when it was getting disposed regardless whether it owned it or not. Starting from EF6 the context honors the `contextOwnsConnection` flag passed to the constructor (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management)). It's not clear from your pseudocode how you instantiate the connection and the context, so presume you create the context in the loop and pass the opened connection. If that's the case you have a few options:

- Upgrade to EF6, or
- Use only one DbContext for all the saves, or
- Load all the records into memory and process them in chunks each in it's own DbContext, or
- Load them in chunks and process them in chunks

If you avoid using the same context for your processing for performance reasons, you can use .AsNoTracking(). There is [an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper) on MSDN on EF performance tuning in case you need more.